# XSL function that return square number list with an parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

I want a function that take an integer parameter n and returns a list of the squares of integers between 1 and n. If n < 1 then the function returns the empty sequence. For this I use the manufacturer XSL sequence.

```
<xsl:function name="squareNumberList" as="xsd:string">
    <!-- use a param that delimite the list -->
    <xsl:param name="value" as="xsd:decimal *"/>
    <!-- create a sequence of the size of $value and containt 1-2-3-...-value -->
    <xsl:sequence name="seq" select="1 to $value"/>
    <!-- if the value if lesser than 1 return empty sequence -->
    <xsl:if test="value &lt; 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$value"></xsl:value>
    </xsl:if>
    <!-- calculate 1*1, 2*2, 3*3 ... value*value and store result in res -->
    <xsl:variable name="res" as="xsd:decimal *"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$seq"> 
            <xsl:sequence select=". * ."/> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- return the result -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$res"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:function>
```

Can you confirm that this function is well defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you making this more complicated than necessary? A simple one-liner:

```
<xsl:sequence select="for $i in 1 to $value return $i * $i" />
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

An XPath 2.0 suggestion was already posted, as XPath 3.0 is supported in Saxon 9.7 (all editions) here is an alternative using `!`:

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:square-list1" as="xs:integer*">
      <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="(1 to $value) ! (. * .)"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

Using higher order functions and `for-each` with commercial editions of Saxon 9.6/7 we can also use

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:square-list2" as="xs:integer*">
      <xsl:param name="value" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="for-each(1 to $value, function($n) { $n * $n })"/>
  </xsl:function>
```